# expo-apple-authentication: "TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'NativeUnimoduleProxy.viewManagersNames')"

Tags: react-native

I went through the expo-apple-authentication documentation and I think that I followed all of the installation and configuration instructions.  However, the emulator is returning the error in the subject line when I try either of the following imports:

```
import * as AppleAuthentication from "expo-apple-authentication";
import AppleAuthenticationButton from "expo-apple-authentication";
```

Any idea what the issue might be or how to debug?  I previously googled this but couldn't find any references to this error.

Answer (score 2):

I've come across the same error message while trying to use the [expo-barcode-scanner](https://github.com/expo/expo/tree/master/packages/expo-barcode-scanner) package.

In order to use this package, you first have to install the [react-native-unimodules](https://github.com/unimodules/react-native-unimodules) package. Its documentation says it is necessary to configure some stuff, one of which is adding some lines of code to the AppDelegate.m file, found inside the ios folder.

The problem was that I forgot to add some lines of code in the `AppDelegate.m` file, more specifically this part:

```
- (NSArray<id<RCTBridgeModule>> *)extraModulesForBridge:(RCTBridge *)bridge
{
  NSArray<id<RCTBridgeModule>> *extraModules = [_moduleRegistryAdapter extraModulesForBridge:bridge];
  // You can inject any extra modules that you would like here, more information at:
  // https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-ios.html#dependency-injection
  return extraModules;
}
```

After adding the code above everything worked!

You can check all necessary changes to the AppDelegate.h and AppDelegate.m files [here](https://gist.github.com/brentvatne/1ece8c32a3c5c9d0ac3a470460c65603)